# A program running my python module always returns a syntax error on the first line after a while loop

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, python-2.7

I'm a beginner at python with experience in Java having to write a python module for a Virtual robot challenge for my high schools MESA(A technology based competition) club. I have been trying to solve this weird problem for days and I only have 6 hours left to fix all the bugs in my code! The "invalid syntax" always occurs on the first line after a while loop here is the relevant information: 
Keep in mind that values have been properly added to the lists

Relevant code:

```
interestlengthl=list()
interestlengthr=list()
interestpoint=list()

def do_examine(robot):
    examinecount=0;
    while (examinecount<(max(interestpoint)) <-the while loop
            i=2+2 <-a innocent line used as an example, this returned an invalid syntax
    maxpoint=max(interestpoint)
    tomove=(currentposition-(max[interestpoint]-interestpoint(examinecount)))
    robot.step_forward(tomove)
    leftscan=robot.sense_steps(robot.SENSOR_LEFT)
    rightscan=robot.sense_steps(robot.SENSOR_RIGHT)
    if (rightscan==interestlengthr(examinecount):
        robot.turn_right()
        do_rowscan(robot)
    if (leftscan==interestlengthl(examinecount):
        robot.turn_left()
        do_rowscan(robot)
    examinecount+=1
    robot.turn_right(2)
    currentposition=robot.sense_steps(robot.SENSOR_FORWARD)
    robot.turn_right(2)
```

Relevant error:

```
File "L:\controllers\controller_zigzag.py", line 35
i=2+2
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Really? Every statement that starts a block (`def, if, for, while, class, try, with`) ends with a `:`

Comment: you need a `:` after `while`, and probably need to unindent `i = 2 + 2` as it's indented further than other indent blocks.

Comment: Forget this, I fixed it. I hadn't closed the opening while parathesis and somehow I forgot to add a : after the while loop line. I fixed that and it worked fine.

Comment: Also the indenting stuff with the i=2+2 was just weird formatting when I copied it over. I had tons of other while loops that I did correctly I have no clue how I spent so much time looking at this and never realized I forgot to add the :. Thanks to those who answered I'm surprised they came in so fast!

Comment: "Forget this"? Mark one of the answers correct if you're satisfied with them!

Answer (score 3):

While loops should have a colon on them, such as with:

```
while examinecount < max (interestpoint):
```

just like your `if` statements further down. And, as an aside, it's not C - you don't need parentheses around the entire conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is that you must place a colon after the loop, AND you have unbalanced brackets:  `while (examinecount<(max(interestpoint))` -> `while (examinecount<(max(interestpoint))):`